# What's the bare minimum Cygwin install to have DDD running properly on XP?

Tags: windows-xp, gdb, cygwin, gnu, ddd-debugger

I’m using the gcc in MinGW that comes with Strawberry Perl, on Windows XP. I’d like to have [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) (the Data Display Debugger) as well but apparently on Windows the simplest way to get ddd is by running Cygwin. So what's the bare minimum of Cygwin I can install to get ddd up and running? I'd prefer if I could run ddd natively on Win32 but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: The cygwin setup program is so yucky that it’s most efficient to just install every package. So it takes a few gigabytes ... don’t forget to rebase all your modules!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell so far, only the following (with Cygwin DLL release version 1.5.25-15), and allowing setup to install any other packages to meet dependencies.
Base: base-files, grep
Develop: ddd, gdb
Math: gnuplot

Answer (score 1):

Example to get grep working: Just drop the following files from a cygwin bin directory into an appropriate directory...
cyggcc_s-1.dll
cygiconv-2.dll
cygintl-8.dll
cygpcre-0.dll
cygwin1.dll
grep.exe

Answer (score 1):

The Cygwin `setup.exe` installer resolves dependencies for you.  Just run the installer, find and enable `ddd`, and click Next.  It might install some packages you doun't strictly need, but figuring out which ones you can safely omit is probably a waste of time.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this; I just install eveything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for minimalism, you might want a smaller X server than [cygwin-x11](http://x.cygwin.com/) (though it's what I use, and I'm quite fond of it). [Starwin X-Win32](http://www.starnet.com/products/xwin32/) is actively maintained (though it costs $$ beyond the trial period), and avoids the overhead of installing Cygwin proper; there are other, zero-cost minimal X servers for win32 available, but I don't have linkage immediately available.

As the documentation at [x.cygwin.com](http://x.cygwin.com/) indicates, the `xorg-x11-base` package is the bare minimum needed.